# Bug while creating new post or page, same post id is being used until hard refresh

Tags: wordpress

I’m facing some problem while adding new posts or pages. When we add a new post of page first time after hard refresh, it completes the operation properly but when we try to add new page without hard refresh, it uses same id of previously created page and updates the data under that id instead of creating new page.

For example if I have created a page which was assigned and ID : 1010. When after publishing this page if I don’t hard refresh and try to add new page, instead of assigning new id of 1011 or something like that, it shows same id 1010 in the url by publishing the new page even. I have tried many options like switching off cache and even I have disabled all plugins and switched the theme to default 2019 or 2017 themes but issue still there.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: @Andreas I have tried many options out of which I mentioned some above like switching theme to default, disabled plugins, turned of server cache, tried to hard refresh on hook of save_post in functions.php but nothing worked. Any kind of help or tip would be appreciated. :)

Comment: Have you checked if the problem persists when trying a different browser?

Comment: Yes @Sjors I have tried it on google chrome and internet explorer but facing same issue with all browsers.

Comment: That's very strange.. You can try reinstalling WordPress, using this method (FTP): https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/how-to-reinstall-wordpress . Make sure to backup first!

Comment: Thank you guys for your prompt replies. I have figured out the issue. We were having dome cache codes in htaccess which was possibly causing issue. I have put the fresh htaccess file with just basic required rules and problem sorted out.